# Test USB-connected SD card reader

Tags: linux, usb, speed, sd-card, card-reader

I'm running a Linux system, so I'm asking a solution that can run on Linux, better if via terminal on a command line.

I have a laptop with an integrated SD card reader, which is connected to motherboard via USB. I just wanted to test its maximum speed, as it is surely not near to unlimited like some completely native card readers like cameras' ones. I mean, if I buy an SD faster than my reader, to use only in my PC, it would be a waste of money, right? Is my speed determined by USB maximums? Or is it a way to test its potential maximum speed without having to buy a secure digital faster than it just to see when it caps? And if it is USB standards dependent, how can I know if it is USB 2.0 or 3.0 connected?

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine it's slower than USB2, and I don't believe that you can get many SD cards fast enough to saturate USB2. UHS-1 cards which are just recently coming out support something like 50-100MB/s maximum, which could saturate it, but those are few and far between.

I can't think of a way to test it without a suitably fast card.

As for seeing if it is USB2 or USB3, you should be able to use `lsusb`. Run it. See what bus the reader is on, then look at the top to see if that is a 3.0 bus or 2.0 bus.

Comment: Thanks. Running lsusb I get some devices with specific names (among them, my wireless cards and other I don't understand) and three USB 2.0 hub with one 3.0. Given that I have a 3.0 and two 2.0 ports, I guess it is a 2.0 connected reader. But isn't USB 2.0 effective speed capped to 35 MB/s? SanDisk "Extreme" cards are guaranteed with a 45 MB/s speed, nevermind "Extreme Pro" with their 95. Is 35 MB/s enough fast for using the card by installing an operating system to it?

Comment: Theoretically it caps at 60MB/s, but realistically around 45. That ought to be fast enough for an OS, considering a typical hard drive is at best twice that fast. I'd be more worried about longevity. Cheap flash tends to fail pretty quickly when used as an OS drive.